# Supplying suggested destination directories to dired

Tags: dired

When I rename files to move them I have a handful of popular destinations that I would like to see in the (pseudo)history so that I can just cursor up to choose one. What I'm thinking is something like what `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` does except instead of suggest commands, suggest destination directory. I know some commands allow you to supply a history but I did not find one for dired. Does such a thing already exist?

Answer (score 1):

1. Customize `dired-dwim-target` to non-`nil`.
2. Advise `dired-dwim-target` to make it use your favorite directory, instead of what it wants to use.

Be aware that this will affect also similar commands that act on the marked files with respect to some directory.  IOW, it will affect not only `C` (copying) but things like renaming and linking.